# Extracting data from another workbook, without mentioning the sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbook. Source workbook and destination workbook.

I would like to extract all the data from my source workbook, depending on the header of my destination workbook.

For this, I have the below code. I would like to know, if it is possible, just to mention workbook name without mentioning the sheet name? Every time I save a new excel file, the sheet saves as sheet1, sheet2. I get an subscript error due to this change in sheet name.

Could any one help, how I can extract data from the sheet without mentioning the sheet name. In most cases, in my workbook, I have only one sheet.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim DestinationWB As Workbook
    Dim OriginWB As Workbook
    Dim path1 As String
    Dim FileWithPath As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim TheHeader As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Set DestinationWB = ThisWorkbook

    ' get the path of this workbook
    path1 = DestinationWB.Path
    FileWithPath = path1 & "\Downloads\Sourcg.xlsx"
    Set OriginWB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FileWithPath)

    'get the count of last row and column
     Lastrow = OriginWB.Worksheets("1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = OriginWB.Worksheets("1").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To LastCol
        'get the name of the field (names are in row 1)
        TheHeader = OriginWB.Worksheets("1").Cells(1, i).Value

        With DestinationWB.Worksheets("S").Range("A4:L4")
            'Find the name of the field (TheHeader) in the destination (in row 4)
            Set cell = .Find(TheHeader, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With

        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            OriginWB.Worksheets("1").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(Lastrow, i)).Copy Destination:=DestinationWB.Worksheets("S_APQP").Cells(5, cell.Column)
        Else
            'handle the error
        End If
    Next i

    OriginWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You may refer to the first worksheet by index `.Worksheets(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mikz, you use property `Worksheets` of `Workbook`. This property contains an ordinary VBA Excel collection (of worksheets). You can access members of any collection by it's *position* (integer) or by it's *key* (string). You use *key* in your code, since you use a string value. If you have the only one worksheet in your workbook, you definitely should use position value, which is 1 - `OriginWB.Worksheets(1).` And it will work regardless of name of the sheet.

If you have more than 1 worksheet, you can traverse through the collection using
`FOR EACH aWorksheet IN OriginWB.Worksheets`

BTW - I would recommend you to use WITH operator for `OriginWB.Worksheets("1")`IMHO it will help you to make shorter and more readable code. You can use nested `WITH` operators.

Comment: yes, 1 without quotes. In other words, you should use `originWB.worksheets(1)` , but not `originWB.worksheets("1")` .

Comment: I tried this, I am getting object does not support this property error

Comment: What do you get for `originWB.Worksheets.Count`? The only reasonable explanation came into my mind is that something definitely wrong with the file. Can you check the object variable `originWB` in Watches section of VBA window right after `Set OriginWB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FileWithPath)` is executed?

Comment: I am getting 16384

Comment: Is this an error number? Or you get this number as a result of the `originWB.Worksheets.Count`? This operation returns the number of worksheets in a workbook :-)...

Comment: I got this result for rows.count :(